# Two dynamic carousel one page flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

i need to add two  dynamic carousel one page.
also minItems and maxItems different .  Other one my min max values are 5,4,2 .

how can i add two slider in to the one page with dynamic change value.

my sliders ids are

1). #home-slider-four

2) #home-slider-five

Any One can help me to fixed this.
Thank you.

```
(function() {

  // store the slider in a local variable
  var $window = $(window),
      flexslider2 , flexslider;

  // tiny helper function to add breakpoints
  function getGridSize() {
    return (window.innerWidth < 600) ? 1 :
           (window.innerWidth < 1220) ? 3 : 4;
  }
  $(function() {
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
  });

  $window.load(function() {
    $('#home-slider-four').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      animationSpeed: 400,
      animationLoop: false,
      itemWidth: 270,
      itemMargin: 20,
      minItems: getGridSize(), // use function to pull in initial value
      maxItems: getGridSize(), // use function to pull in initial value
      start: function(slider2){
       flexslider2 = slider2;
      }
    });

  });

  // check grid size on resize event
  $window.resize(function() {
    var gridSize = getGridSize();
    flexslider2.vars.minItems = gridSize;
    flexslider2.vars.maxItems = gridSize;

  });
}());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This
define a function call "function slider" and for that function pass class name or id

```
function slider(elemname,minIt,maxIt) {



 // store the slider in a local variable
  var $window = $(window),
      flexslider2 , flexslider;

  // tiny helper function to add breakpoints
  function getGridSize() {
    return (window.innerWidth < 600) ? 1 :
           (window.innerWidth < 1220) ? minIt : maxIt;
  }



$(function() {
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
  });


    $(elemname).flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      animationSpeed: 400,
      animationLoop: false,
      itemWidth: 270,
      itemMargin: 20,
      minItems: getGridSize(), // use function to pull in initial value
      maxItems: getGridSize(), // use function to pull in initial value
      start: function(slider2){
       flexslider2 = slider2;
      }

  });

  // check grid size on resize event
  $window.resize(function() {
    var gridSize = getGridSize();
    flexslider2.vars.minItems = gridSize;
    flexslider2.vars.maxItems = gridSize;

  });
}
```

and call this function inside document.ready function
i.e.

```
slider("<Your class name or id name>");
```

in your case it should be

```
slider("#home-slider-four",3,4); and slider("#home-slider-five",4,5);
```

Answer (score 3):

I have forked a fiddle with multiple Demo

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/Q26g3/26/)**

**jQuery**

```
  // The slider being synced must be initialized first
  $('#reviews-slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    //other options
    asNavFor: '#main-slider'
    controlsContainer: '.flex-container'
  });

  $('#main-slider').flexslider({
    //other options
    sync: "#reviews-slider"
  });
```

Note the `asNavFor`, `controlsContainer` and `sync` in options

More Info on Multiple Slider: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the flex slider plugin, but I have used other jQuery powered gallery/carousels.

I **think** all you really need to do is create another jQuery object with flexslider API options, similar to what you've done with #home-slider-four

Example:

```
$('#home-slider-four').flexslider({ // options here // });
$('#home-slider-five').flexslider({ // different options here // });
```

That should do it.

Again, I've never used flex slider, so I'm unsure if this will work. This technique does work with RoyalSlider.

Best of luck!